# Ex-Company Group Policy not enabling me to do Windows updates

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I left my ex-company a really long time ago (3 years). They "said" that they removed group policy but obviously did half a job. Unfortunately their group policy is still dominating my machine and I want to remove it. I have admin rights, but I cannot turn on my firewall (greyed out) or do Windows updates (get error code 8024402C).

If I run gpedit I get an error "Failed to open the Group Policy object on this computer as you do not have appropriate rights". I fear that there is a system administrator role that is not allowing me to do anything.

How can I get rid of it and the system administrator role without having to go back to the ex-company?

In my user folder are my old user ID and one of the Administrators ID from when I worked there. Yet it is not displayed when I go into User Accounts or Switch User.

I am on 64-bit Windows 7 Professional.

I also checked for Network bridges and I have none.

If I open Services I cannot stop the Group Policy service (greyed out) even though I am an Administrator.

I am also not connected to a Domain (via Computer Properties); I am connected to a Workgroup. But if I click on network ID, it says that the computer is part of a business network. I then change it to a home PC, it says restart will update this change, and when I restart it, it is back to the business network. So it won't allow me to change it.

Comment: Enable the built-in Administrator account then create a non-domain Administrator account you can use

Comment: You might not be connected to a domain but your clear using the domain account if the existing group policy is being applied.  You can also use the built-in Administrator to get rid of the existing policies

Comment: 8024402C = WU_E_PT_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED Same as ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED - the proxy server
or target server name cannot be resolved. so check your proxy settings in IE options->connections

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Andre - I have no proxy settings on IE options, it is just auto detect ticked.

Comment: Ramhound I am going to try the create new administrator non domain account and I will try get rid of the policies. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have done everything within your power to remove the system from the domain, except the policies applied still persist.

Based on everything you've said, you are going to need to extract the license key for windows reinstall the os completely.

Comment: Downvoting without having offered a viable solution yourself, or commenting with anything constructive is not helpful.